# bash regexp to find lines with duplicate words

Tags: regex, bash, backreference

I have a file with lines like this:

```
"def{word}  def{word}"
"def{worad} def{worads}"
```

and I want to report braced words that occur twice.
So the output should, in this case, be just "word"
What I have is:

```
#!/bin/bash
arr=(
   "def{word}  def{word}"
   "def{worad} def{worads}"
)
for i in "${arr[@]}"; do 
   [[ $i =~ def\{([a-z]+)\}.*def\{\1\} ]] || continue
   echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
done
```

i.e., I try to match the first word with \1 (a back reference). However, the output is nil.
How can I do this?

Comment: Well your regex works fine for me in my regex tester. So it seems to be something to do with the bash side of things. Maybe try simplifying to take the array out and just test on a single string.

Comment: But doing it in Bash seems unnatural. `sed -n s/def{\([^}]*\)} *def{\1}/\1/p' file`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find bash regular expressions behave better when enclosed in quotes, even though you have to be a bit careful with this, as direct quoting will cause *exact* instead of *regex* matching.  To get around this, you can put your regular expression in a variable, quoted, and then reference it in your `=~` expression:

```
#!/bin/bash
arr=(
   "def{word}  def{word}"
   "def{worad} def{worads}"
)
re="def\{([a-z]+)\}.*def\{\1\}"
for i in "${arr[@]}"; do 
   [[ $i =~ $re ]] || continue
   echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
done
```

Output:

```
$ ./worad.sh 
word
$
```

This only seems to work in Bash v4, though.

Comment: Did you test this? Bash regexes don't support backreferences, and this doesn't work.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Yes - I did test it - on bash version 4.x (e.g. Ubuntu 14.04), where the backreferences *do* work.  However it does not work on bash 3.2.x (e.g. OS X) - see tripleee's edit.  Simplified test command: `re="([a-z])[0-9]\1"; [[ a1a =~ $re ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[0]}`

Comment: So strange, it doesn't work for me in Bash 4.3.42 (MSYS2), even though `man 3 regex` mentions backreferences...

Comment: And why does Chet's [Bash FAQ](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/FAQ) only mention backreferences as "not in Bash 4.3" and "maybe implement in the future"?

Comment: @BenjaminW. I see "backreferences in pattern matching" in the "New things in ksh-93 not in bash-4.3", but nothing about regex backreferences.  [Pattern matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html) in bash != regex (in [bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs) or elsewhere).

Comment: I'm not familiar with MSYS2, but it is possible that the underlying `regexec()`  call is different in this respect.  Almost certainly what you have in windows will vary from the glibc version.

Answer (score 1):

Using sed

```
sed -n '/\({[^{]*}\).*\1/p' file

"def{word}  def{word}"
```

If only export the word

```
sed  -n 's/.*{\([^{]*\)}.*{\1}.*/\1/p' file

word
```

Answer (score 0):

for loops in bash are really slow, and this is probably a little complicated for bash.  I'd recommend python or awk for this.  Here's some code in python to do what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re
import sys 
import itertools

def freq(alist):
    counts = {}
    for x in alist:
        x = x[1:-1]
        counts[x] = counts.get(x,0) + 1 
    return {m:[j[0] for j in n] for m,n in itertools.groupby(counts.iteritems(), lambda y: y[1])}

for line in sys.stdin:
    counts = freq(re.findall(r'\{[^}]*\}', line))
    if 2 in counts:
        print ' '.join(counts[2])
    else:
        print
```

Assuming this script is in a file called two.py run like this:

```
cat yourfile | python two.py
```

Now that it's in python, you have something that's much easier to extend and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, many ways to do this, including:

```
perl -lne '/def\{(.+?)\}.*def\{\1\}/ and print $1' filename
```